# Read file in grails

Tags: java, grails, groovy

So I have a few .drlt files (normal txt files that serves me as templates for rule engine) and 
I need to read them and put in to some static string variable in bootstrap of application.

I just cannot figure out **where** to put it in grails application and **how** to read them.

I've tried put them to src/java and read them from src/grails, domain, service etc. None of that worked. The only thing that worked is to put it into grails-app/conf and read them like this:

```
def classLoader = Thread.currentThread().contextClassLoader
def fileReader = classLoader.getResourceAsStream('my-file.drlt').newReader()
```

But I don't want to put my template files in config directory.
I've read many posts and 'solutions' for this problem but non of them are good solutions. Is it really possible that this is unable to do nice in such a stable framework as Grails?

Thanks for any help,
Ivan

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since Grails is a well structured Spring application you can take advantage of `Resource` and `ResourceLoader` to load your text file. The `grailsResourceLocator` makes using these quite simple (be sure to inject it into your bean). Using these classes you can locate your file within the `src/java` or `src/groovy` directories and treat it as any other class resource.

So for example, if your file is in `src/java/com/example/textfile.txt` then your can access it as a `File` using `grailsResourceLocator.findResourceForURI('classpath:/com/example/textfile.txt').getFile()`

A detailed example can be found within this [blog post](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2013/09/grails-goodness-accessing-resources.html) and the API documentation for [Resource](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/core/io/Resource.html) may help as well.

This is the *correct* way to handle resources within your Grails application.

Comment: Yep, the API is a cool abstraction because you don't have to think about the very different file layouts between the dev environment and an exploded deployed WAR file, or even consider how you'd access the files if the WAR wasn't expanded.